# UIDocumentInteractionController showing preview in simulator but not in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to implement UIDocumentInteractionController in my app which can make a PDF out of selected photos. All works perfectly in the simulator, but when I test it on an iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1, nothing happens when I try to preview the PDF. Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)viewPDFButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.PDFFilePath];
    NSLog(self.PDFFilePath);
    if (URL) {
        // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

       // Preview PDF
       [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Of course, I have also implemented this:

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller
{
    return self;
}
```

I am not sure where the issue is, it might be something trivial, so any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Check the return value of `presentPreviewAnimated:`, if it returns `NO` it means that the system isn't able to display that file, which means either the file doesn't exist (can't be opened) or the file is corrupted somehow, or isn't a PDF file...